# Проблема с добавлением данных в БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Есть таблица `Image`. В ней есть несколько полей (интересуют `id` `ImageName`, они должны быть равны).

Щас так:

```
Images img = new Images
{
    ImageName = (_productContext.Images.Count() > 0 ? (Convert.ToInt32(await _productContext.Images.MaxAsync(x => x.Id)) + 1).ToString() : "0")
};
await _productContext.Images.AddAsync(img)
```

но это очень криво. Как правильно прировнять инкрименту до сохранения в БД???
Может как то можно сделать с другой стороны: например при уделении элемента в MySql если есть `id` `1,2,3` , удалить `3`, а потом добавить один элемент, то добавить `4`, получается что `3` пропускается (может как то можно это обойти?)

Comment: Сделайте автоинкремент и не мучайтесь. Не надо это обходить. Айдишники не предназначены для красоты, айдишники не предназначены для просмотра человеком. Они предназначены для компьютера. Если в них будут пропуски - это нормально.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov автоинкремент у меня id. но мне нужно чтобы ImageName было такое же как и id всегда. Но в данный момент если удалить с таблиц последнюю запись, то имя становится различным от `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> мне нужно чтобы ImageName было такое же как и id всегда

Не стоит так делать. Во-первых, id может поменяться. Например, при переходе на другую СУБД, или при слиянии данных из разных БД, или при изменении схемы. Поэтому привязывать id, предназначенный для работы движка СУБД к полю, предназначенному для просмотра человеком, не следует.

Во-вторых, ваш код легко нарвётся на проблемы, если к БД обращаются несколько клиентов (или потоков). Например, вы получаете значение с помощью `MaxAsync`, потом другой клиент/поток добавляет строку в таблицу, после чего ваше значение устаревает и становится неверным.

---

Что можно сделать, оставаясь в рамках EF?

Сперва объект без поля `ImageName` записать в БД, потом получить `Id`, сгенерированный для этого объекта и обновить `ImageName`. Примерно, так:

```
Images img = new Images();
await _productContext.Images.AddAsync(img);
await _productContext.SaveChangesAsync();

img.ImageName = img.Id.ToString();
await _productContext.Images.UpdateAsync(img);
await _productContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

На возражение, что при этом делаются несколько запросов в БД (insert и update - итого два), есть простой ответ: приведённый в вопросе код тоже делает *несколько* запросов: `Count` (кстати, его следовало бы заменить на `CountAsync`), `MaxAsync`, `AddAsync` - итого три.

---

Возможны подходы без строгой опоры на Entity Framework.

Использовать триггер в БД. Этот триггер при вставке будет задавать значение для `ImageName`.

Ещё можно сделать поле `ImageName` вычисляемым. Оно вообще не хранится, а вычисляется на лету.

---

А вообще, раз уж значение всё равно генерируется автоматически, то можно генерировать его на клиенте. Например, использовать GUID.